Allow Access to Limited API EndPoints
I have a custom policy that will restrict access to certain API endpoints in Mule. The policy template.xml and yaml file is given below (Disclaimer: Mind you this may not be a good implementation overall as I am just getting started)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:http-policy="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy"
    xmlns:http-transform="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy-transform"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy/current/mule-http-policy.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy-transform http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http-policy-transform/current/mule-http-policy-transform.xsd">
    <http-policy:proxy name="{{{policyId}}}-custom-policy">
        <http-policy:source>
            <try>
                <choice>
                    {{#clientID}}             
                    <when expression="#['{{{.}}}'!={{{clientIdExpression}}}]">
                        <logger level="INFO" message="Route Found"/>
                    </when>
                    {{/clientID}}                
                    <otherwise>
                        <raise-error type="CUSTOM:NOT_ALLOWED" 
                            description="#['Access Denied for this API resource']"/>
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
                <error-handler>
                    <on-error-propagate type="CUSTOM:NOT_ALLOWED">
                        <http-transform:set-response statusCode="403">
                            <http-transform:body>#[
                                output application/json
                                ---
                                {"error": "Access Forbidden"}]
                            </http-transform:body>
                        </http-transform:set-response>
                    </on-error-propagate>
                </error-handler>
            </try>
            <http-policy:execute-next/>
        </http-policy:source>
    </http-policy:proxy>
</mule>

YAML file
#YAML File
id: Test
name: Test
description: Custom Policy used to restrict client access at API EndPoint level. This is designed to use with OpenId Connect access token enforcement policy.
category: Custom
type: custom
violationCategory: authentication
resourceLevelSupported: true
encryptionSupported: false
standalone: true
requiredCharacteristics: []
providedCharacteristics: []
configuration:  
  - propertyName: clientIdExpression
    name: Client ID Expression
    description: Mule Expression to be used to extract the Client ID from API requests
    type: string
    defaultValue: "authentication.properties.userProperties.client_id"
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: false
  - propertyName: clientName
    name: Client Name
    description: Name of the external client that uses this policy
    type: string
    defaultValue: []
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: false 
  - propertyName: clientID
    name: Client ID
    description: Client ID that needs to be restricted
    type: string
    optional: false
    sensitive: false
    allowMultiple: true
    defaultValue: []

As per the screenshot below (which is the policy configuration), it is going to restrict access to the endpoints /api/endpoint-1 and /api/endpoint-2, for the client_id: fbcfa238-2071-42c6-8e16-c9f8890249df.

If I need to reverse the behaviour (i.e to allow access to only the endpoints /api/endpoint-1 and /api/endpoint-2, for the client_id: fbcfa238-2071-42c6-8e16-c9f8890249df), what changes can be made in the custom policy? Any insights is greatly appreciated.

To allow access only to the configured endpoints, simply change the condition in the choice to "==" instead of "!=". However, this leaves other endpoints in your API unsecured.
Consider an API with three endpoints: endpoint1, endpoint2, and endpoint3. Now the updated policy implementation permits the client with ID fbcfa238-2071-42c6-8e16-c9f8890249df to access endpoints 1 and 2 as intended. But this client can also access endpoint 3. This occurs because endpoint 3 remains unsecured by the custom policy configuration, which is a result of selecting the option to "apply configuration to specific API methods & resources".
To secure your API fully, apply another instance of the custom policy to protect the remaining endpoints with a client ID that isn't easily predictable. Your policy configurations in API manager would then look like this:
Policy 1 (Allowing access to specific endpoints):

Client 1 - fbcfa238-2071-42c6-8e16-c9f8890249df
Allowed endpoints = endpoint1 and endpoint2

Policy 2 (Securing remaining endpoints):

Random client = UnexposedClientID
Allowed endpoint = endpoint3

Now, the endpoint 3 is effectively not exposed to any client. If you later decide to expose endpoint 3 to a different client or even to the same client as in Policy 1, you'll need to update the Policy 2 configuration accordingly.  This would typically involve replacing the random client ID (UnexposedClientID) with the actual client ID you wish to grant access to.

thank you very much for the explanation. I did try with "==" but didn't get the achieved results. However, after adding the random client, it's working :)
